# install pg_stat_monitor on edb advanced server

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb

I started playing with `edb advanced server` and got it installed on `Rocky Linux`. It is working fine with no issues.

I now want to install `percona pg_stat_monitor` extension using `dnf`.

This extension is available via `PostgreSQL dnf repositories`.

When I install the extension via PostgreSQL dnf repositories, It installs `postgres server` with it as a dependency.

This results in 2 postgres instances running on my server. i.e. 1 from edb and the other from PostgreSQL.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

All I want is to install the postgres `pg_stat_monitor` [extension](https://github.com/percona/pg_stat_monitor#installing-from-postgresql-yum-repositories) on my `edb Advanced server`.

thanks

Comment: You cannot install the PGDG binaries with EDB's fork. Try to build from source.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe ok but it requires `pg_config` in path and the location for `pg_config` is `/usr/edb/as14/bin/pg_config` so need to find a way to put it in the `$PATH`

Comment: That should be as simple as `export PATH=/usr/edb/as14/bin:$PATH`.